# Any instructions given by contemporary prominent preachers on how to receive the gift of tongues?

Tags: spiritual-gifts, speaking-in-tongues

Is there any method/instruction given by prominent preachers recently on how to receive the gift of tongues? Some specific way of prayer, some specific steps to follow, what kind of attitude is required and so forth?

Comment: I think "contemporary prominent preachers" is very broad (especially for this topic); there is a wide range of opinion - are you interested in a specific group?

Comment: @RyanFrame I don't think there will be many preachers who gave this kind of instructions. As you think that this is very broad, I assume that you know some preachers who give instructions on how to receive the gift of tongues. If so, please mention at least one. I really want to know.

Comment: DJClayworth answered well, so I think I withdraw my objection to the question. But I have heard "if God wants you to have it, He'll give it to you, so don't worry about it," "if you want it, pray faithfully and God may (or may not) give it to you," "it is passed on through prayer and the laying on of hands," and "fake it until you make it." Given this site's definition of Christianity, the fourth is as valid an answer as the previous three.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overlooking the most important word in your question, and that is 'gift'. A gift is something that is freely given - the giver chooses whether or not to give, and the receiver can only choose whether or not to accept it - if it is given. If the receiver can compel the giver in any way, or tries to earn it, then it isn't a gift. It's long been part of Christian theology that Tongues and rather supernatural abilities are 'gifts' in that sense. Check out 1 Corinthians 12, where this is made explicit. Also check out 1 Corinthians 13, which is an explanation of something better and more important than spiritual gifts - Love. It's not accidental that those chapters are next to each other.

General advice as far as I know is that if you earnestly desire a specific gift, keep praying for it. But be aware, as with all other prayers, God may not grant you what you are asking. He may have a better, alternative plan for you.

The exceptions to this are the Pentecostal traditions where speaking in tongues is a sure and necessary sign of being a true believer. In that case if you don't have that gift, consult with a Pastor.

Comment: What are these "Pentecostal traditions" exactly, and why at this point does tongues no-longer become a gift? That last paragraph seems to contradict the rest of your answer (which I thought was really good).

Comment: Some branches of Pentecostalism believe that the gift of tongues is *always* given to a believer who has received the Baptism of the Spirit. They still consider it to be a 'gift'. The first paragraphs describe the beliefs of most Christians (those who accept the genuineness of the supernatural gifts), and the last one specific branch of Christianity.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Be nice if we ask just had a single common view!